# How would I render a Choice field into a template with each radio choice

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

As said, how would I render a Choice field into a template with each radio choice rendering separately for which I can have a control over every individual choices.

This is what had been done so far.

models.py

```
First = 0
Business = 1
Economy = 2
CLASS = (
    (First, 'First'),
    (Business, 'Business'),
    (Economy, 'Economy'),
)

class Lead(models.Model):
    ....
    class_type  = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, choices = CLASS)
```

form.py

```
class Lead_form(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = ['class_type']

widgets = {
...
'class_type' : forms.RadioSelect(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'ClasstypeRadios'  }),
...
}
```

html

```
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Class Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="ClasstypeRadios" id="ClasstypeRadios1" value="0" checked=""> First<i class="input-helper"></i>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="ClasstypeRadios" id="ClasstypeRadios2" value="1"> Business <i class="input-helper"></i>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
....
```

This is so far I've tried but there is still something missing.
As can be seen, the radio buttons are dealing differently but not as a "li" tag which is the default way to render by django into templates via {{ form.class_type }} but rather, I would like to render them individually to have a control over every one of the choices.
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768635/12280790

What am I missing.

Comment: Boolean field with string choices?

Comment: my bad. edited.

Comment: Have you seen the example on rendering radio buttons manually in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect)?